# Disabling DejaGnu Options

Tags: c, testing, gcc, toolchain

Does anybody know how i can disable flag which written at the source code of the file, without changing source code of this file. Maybe i must change one of .exp files?

I want to disable flag `-pthread` without changing this source code:

```
// { dg-do run { target *-*-linux* } }
// { dg-options "-pthread" }
#include <pthread.h>
#include <cxxabi.h>
extern "C" int printf (const char *, ...);
int main()
{
  try
    {
      pthread_exit (0);
    }
  catch (abi::__forced_unwind &)
    {
      printf ("caught forced unwind\n");
      throw;
    }
  catch (...)
    {
      printf ("caught ...\n");
      return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can, however as `-pthread` on *-*-linux targets simply expands to `-D_REENTRANT` and `-lpthread` maybe you could provide a replacement `libpthread` and add `-L` *dir* to the test flags, so that the system `libpthread.so` isn't linked to.

That will of course prevent the program linking if you don't provide a definition of `pthread_exit`.